# Bad file descriptor upon writing to message queue with O_WRONLY flag

Tags: c, linux, posix, message-queue

I have the following program that errors out `Client unable to send message to server: Bad file descriptor`, which is inside the `Transmit()` function.

From what I looked up about this error, it seems to happen when the permissions aren't correct but in my case, I open the same message queue with `O_WRONLY` flag in `Transmit()` and try to write to it.

Basically I'm just trying to write a simple producer-consumer program where the consumer remains blocked producer sends something to it.

Just to confirm: the message queue in `Transmit()` does refer to the same message queue being used in `Receive()` based on the `NAME`, yes?

```
#define MAX_MESSAGES      10
#define MAX_BUFF_SIZE     180
#define MSG_BUFF_SIZE     MAX_BUFF_SIZE + 10
#define QUEUE_PERMISSIONS 0660

static pthread_t rxHdlr;
static pthread_t txHdlr;

static void* Transmit(void* arg);
static void* Receive(void* arg);

char readBuffer [MSG_BUFF_SIZE];
char writeBuffer [MSG_BUFF_SIZE];

#define NAME   "/sp-sample"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   

    if (pthread_create(&rxHdlr, NULL, Receive, NULL) != 0)
    {
        printf("Fail to create a server thread!\n");
    }

    if (pthread_create(&txHdlr, NULL, Transmit, NULL) != 0)
    {
        printf ("fail to create a client thread\n");
    }

    while(1);
}

static void* Receive(void* arg)
{
    struct mq_attr attr;
    static mqd_t mqd;       

    attr.mq_flags = 0;
    attr.mq_maxmsg = MAX_MESSAGES;
    attr.mq_msgsize = MAX_BUFF_SIZE;
    attr.mq_curmsgs = 0;

    mq_unlink(NAME);

    if ((mqd = mq_open (NAME, O_RDONLY | O_CREAT, 0644, &attr)) == -1) 
    {
        printf ("mq_open failed in UartRx: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit (1);
    }


    while(1)
    {
        int iret = mq_receive(mqd, readBuffer, sizeof(readBuffer), NULL);
        if (iret == -1)
        {   
            printf ("Errno: %d\n", errno);
        }
        printf ("Received buffer: %s\n", readBuffer);
    }
}


static void* Transmit(void* arg)
{
    int iRet;
    mqd_t mqd;  
    char buffer[100] = "TX data!";

    if (mqd = mq_open (NAME, O_WRONLY) == -1) 
    {
        printf ("TX MqOpen failed - %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit (1);
    }

    while(1)
    {
        if (mq_send (mqd, buffer, strlen (buffer) + 1, 0) == -1) 
        {
            perror ("Client unable to send message to server"); // ERROR!
        }
    }

}
```

**Edit:**

I was able to get past this issue of Bad File Descriptor as mentioned in the answer below however looks to me both `Transmit()` and `Receive()` are blocked, and I don't see any transmission happening

Answer (score 1):

```
if (mqd = mq_open (NAME, O_WRONLY) == -1)
```

Is incorrect because `==` has higher precedence than `=`. Needs to be:

```
if ((mqd = mq_open (NAME, O_WRONLY)) == -1)
```

Not directly related to the problem in the question but note that `while(1);` is a very bad way to ensure that the `main` thread doesn't exit. That chews up CPU doing essentially no productive work. A better way would be use `pthread_join` to wait for the child threads to exit. The latter is preferred because it will put the thread to sleep rather than spin the CPU.

Comment: They got it right in the `Receive()` function.

Comment: yeah that must be it. Also after making this change, the `Receive()` thread doesn't seem to receive anything. and regarding your other point, are you implying to use `pthread_join` inside main that ensures threads are actually sleeping while blocked? Coming from RTOS, I imagined as long as the thread is blocked, it isn't utilizing processing time

Comment: "blocked" in the context you refer to means blocked at the OS level and thus doesn't need to be scheduled until the thread needs to wake. The code you have is blocked at the user level but not the OS level. Which means the OS scheduler still needs to run the thread to spin that loop and hence consume CPU.

Comment: Right. And `pthread_join` blocks `main` in this case (if I had one in main) and waits for the threads to terminate (which isn't happening). How can you actually block the thread so it's not constantly wasting resources and wakes up only when the message queue is populated for instance?

Comment: `mq_receive` already does that by default (and why I only commented on the `main` loop and not the child thread loops). From the [mq_receive man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_receive.3.html): "*If the queue is empty, then, by default, mq_receive() blocks until a message becomes available*"

Comment: that's what I thought too. So your point was only about blocking the `main` right? Sorry seemed to have confused. Also, do you see why the message isn't successfully sent/received?

Comment: Yes `main` only. For the send/receive problem please ask a new question. I'll take a look if I have time and others will more easily see it too.

Comment: @xyf: If you had used `-Wall`, as everyone always should, you'd have got a warning about this line: https://godbolt.org/z/x6qcoqqva